# Agregar menu de accion en un fragmento, Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Buenas!!
Estoy tratando de agregar una action bar a un fragmento, pero no consigo ni en el xml ni en java.
Este seria mi menu de acciones

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_facial_scan"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_facial_action"
    android:title="@string/facial_scan"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Este es el xml de mi fragmento

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightBackground"
tools:context=".fragments.EmptyFragment">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_enterprise_logo"/>
```

y este seria el codigo en java

```
    package com.idtknology.identytech.identymanage.fragments;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class EmptyFragment extends Fragment {
public EmptyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_empty, container, false);
}
```

}

Agradeceria cualquier ayuda!!

Comment: Quieres crear un menú en el fragmento que muestre item diferentes a los de la actividad?

Comment: sii! quiero que este fragmento tenga un menu de accion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente debes sobreescribir los métodos correspondientes que uno siempre debe utilizar a la hora de emplear menus: estos métodos son:

```
OnCreateOptionsMenu()
```

y

```
OnOptionsItemSelected()
```

Debes implementar lo siguiente a la clase de tu fragmento:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.nombre_de_tu_fragmento, menu); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_facial_scan){

            //El código que se ejecutara al hacer click en esa opción

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Para que todo esto funcione debes implementar una tercera cosa en tu fragmento.
En el método onCreate de tu fragmento(si no tienes un método onCreate agregalo) debes incluir setHasOptionsMenu(true);

De tal modo que tu método onCreate se vería asi:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

Por supuesto debes implementar este fragmento en tu clase, tienes dos formas dinamicamente:

Supongamos que la clase de tu fragmento se llama MiMenu, entonces deberias instanciarla en la clase donde quieres añadir el fragmento:

```
MiMenu miMenuFragmento/*por ejemplo */= new  MiMenu();


FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_contenedor_del_fragmento, miMenuFragmento/*el nombre que le dimos a la instancia*/).commit();
```

o a través de xml añadiendo esto a el xml donde quieres que aparezca el fragmento:

```
<fragment
    android:layout:width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/id_de_tu_fragmento" //id de tu fragmento
    android:name="..." //nombre completo de tu fragmento
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_your_fragment_name"> //nombre de tu fragmento
```

Por último recuerda que los fragmentos incluidos a a través de xml no se pueden remplazar por otros, para remplazarlos debes incluirlos dinamicamente

Comment: Gracias!! con el tercer paso ya solucionaba lo que estaba queriendo hacer.

Comment: De nada, es muy importante que des la respuesta por aceptada entonces para que otros se puedan beneficiar, no lo olvides.